# Reminding Users to Upvote Comment or Question

Tags: discussion, comments, up-votes

Would it be an acceptable practice to remind users who are effectively approving comments or questions to upvote them?

For example:

I've helped some users with a comment, they found it useful but didn't upvote it.

Shouldn't I remind them to upvote this comment?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, that's not where [comment upvotes are for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up):

> When you vote up, you are moving that content "up" so it will be seen by more people.

If it's really helpful, the relevant information should be edited into the question or answer, and the **comment should be deleted**, not upvoted.

Upvoting comments only has benefits when there are many of them

> - Upvotes on a comment help ensure the comment remains visible when there are many comments on a post, but do not give the author any reputation.

which is usually an indication that the comments [aren't used for their intended purpose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):

> #### When should I comment?
>
> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request **clarification** from the author;
> - Leave **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but **minor or transient information** to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).